# How can I pull two objects together without scaling them

Tags: modeling

It might seem like a trivial question, but I do this a lot when modeling, and I always have to manually move each part instead of pulling them together or pushing them apart because doing so would scale them down or up.
For example, imagine you have two cubes that have a scale value of 1, and you want to pull them together equally, but without changing their size. Is there a way to move the cubes without scaling them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the *3D View* header, open the *Options* overlay and toggle *Locations* on
[image]

Comment: @Throndronis And like moving objects with G, by hitting X, Y or Z resp. Shift and X, Y or Z you can constrain the movement to certain axes.

Comment: they really need to put this somewhere better. Yes once you know it's there it's good but man it's hidden so well!

Answer (score 1):

Push/Pull exists. I learned about this earlier this year and it's super useful.
[image: Push/Pull 3.3a]